# Disable select option when user choose Chemex

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
 <tr>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Coffe</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <select class="size">
               <option value="" selected disabled>Select Size</option>
               <option>Large</option>
               <option value="" class="">Medium</option>
               <option value="" class="">Small</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select>
               <option value="">Espresso</option>
               <option value="" class="">Cappuccino</option>
               <option value="" class="">Americano</option>
               <option value="" class="">Pour over</option>
               <option value="" class="Chemex" id ="Chemex">Chemex</option>
           </select>
       </td>
```

I would to disable select size when user choose Chemex, how can I do it, thank you. I think I could do it with eventListener but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change` event listener, with `disabled` attribute for `.size`, in order to disable the `.size` select. Also, you need to provide `value` attribute, for each `<option>`.

```js
let sel = document.querySelector(".some-class");

sel.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  if (sel.value == "Chemex"){
    document.querySelector(".size").disabled = true;
  } else{
    document.querySelector(".size").disabled = false; 
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<tr>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Coffe</th>
        <th>Extras</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <select class="size">
               <option value="" selected disabled>Select Size</option>
               <option>Large</option>
               <option value="" class="">Medium</option>
               <option value="" class="">Small</option>
           </select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select class="some-class">
               <option value="Espresso">Espresso</option>
               <option value="Cappuccino" class="">Cappuccino</option>
               <option value="Americano" class="">Americano</option>
               <option value="Pour over" class="">Pour over</option>
               <option value="Chemex" class="Chemex" id ="Chemex">Chemex</option>
           </select>
       </td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed your youtube channel. I spent freakin 2 night for this line of code

Comment: @QuangAnhBui It happens. But you have to stay calm and focused! And, thanks for following my channel. :)

Comment: checkout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in jQuery like that

```js
$('.some-class').on('change', function() {
  var sc = $(this).val();
  $('.size').attr('disabled', false)
  if (sc === 'Chemex') {
    console.log(sc)
    $('.size').attr('disabled', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th>Size</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Coffe</th>
  <th>Extras</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select class="size">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Size</option>
      <option>Large</option>
      <option value="" class="">Medium</option>
      <option value="" class="">Small</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="some-class">
      <option value="Espresso">Espresso</option>
      <option value="Cappuccino" class="">Cappuccino</option>
      <option value="Americano" class="">Americano</option>
      <option value="Pour over" class="">Pour over</option>
      <option value="Chemex" class="Chemex" id="Chemex">Chemex</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```